# Determine space above element with elastic scrolling in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a simple *pull to refresh* function in Javascript for iOS, but am running into some problems.

The main problem is I want to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` with it, so that the element can have smooth scrolling. Then if the element is scrolled too far down, it will show the element that will "refresh".

On iOS, with elastic scrolling, if you pull down on an element there is space above it. Is it possible to calculate the height of this space? If it is, I would be able to see if it exceeded a certain limit, and if it did, run a function to handle the "refreshing."

Are there other ways to do this? I am not going to use iScroll or jQuery Mobile (I am using regular jQuery, however) as they will add unnecessary functions to my app that will not be used.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it beyond figuring it out yourself: **use iScroll.** If you really can't stand having features you're not using, look at the iScroll source code and figure out how it works. At some point, it just doesn't make sense to re-create what someone else has already done a good job creating. **For free.** How much is your time worth?

Comment: This sounds like it would cause a "lag-like" issue which is why I think it would be best to do like the face book app and have a "static-sized" element that simply says "Refresh" or something of that nature and leave it at that

Comment: @MattBall I see no reason why trying to improve upon an existing way to do something is a waste of time. More importantly, I can't reverse engineer iScroll to use `-webkit-mobile-scrolling`, it relies on their non native scrolling features, which is always laggy for me.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Doesn't the Fb app have a drag to refresh function?

Comment: yea, on the main news feed screen. I'm not for certain, but its prolly just another basic XML feed